# MySQL query suddenly takes forever to finish

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I'm having a problem with an old Symfony 2 application. Suddenly, when the user clicks on the Orders tab, it takes 5+ minutes to display the list, when it used to take no more than 3 seconds before. This is the query with its execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT DISTINCT s0_.id AS id0 
              , SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount) AS sclr1
              , SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount * s1_.tax) AS sclr2
              , SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount * s1_.retax) AS sclr3
              , s0_.id AS id4 
           FROM stncrp_order s0_ 
           JOIN stncrp_store s2_ 
             ON s0_.store_id = s2_.id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN stncrp_orderline s1_ 
             ON s0_.id = s1_.order_id 
            AND s1_.rejected = 0
           LEFT 
           JOIN stncrp_order_provider_warn s3_ 
             ON s0_.id = s3_.order_id 
          WHERE s0_.state >= 3 
          GROUP 
             BY s0_.id
              , s0_.date
              , s0_.shipment_limit_date
              , s0_.state
              , s0_.state_changed_date
              , s0_.received
              , s0_.shipment_cost
              , s0_.username
              , s0_.notes
              , s0_.user_id
              , s0_.store_id
              , s0_.storedata_id
              , s3_.id
              , s3_.createdDate
              , s3_.comments
              , s3_.order_id 
          ORDER 
             BY s0_.id DESC 
          LIMIT 10 
         OFFSET 0;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref                 | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s0_   | ALL    | IDX_F4A5D9B092A811   | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                | 19633 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s2_   | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY              | 4       | est_db.s0_.store_id |     1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s1_   | ref    | IDX_252BF9D78D9F6D38 | IDX_252BF9D78D9F6D38 | 5       | est_db.s0_.id       |     3 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s3_   | ref    | IDX_20FC41F28D9F6D38 | IDX_20FC41F28D9F6D38 | 5       | est_db.s0_.id       |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Here's the process list on the server right now:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host            | db     | Command | Time | State               | Info                                                                                                 |
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 185 | root | localhost:52066 | est_db | Sleep   | 4877 |                     | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 186 | root | localhost:52068 | est_db | Sleep   | 4885 |                     | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 209 | root | localhost:52176 | est_db | Sleep   |   31 |                     | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 242 | root | localhost       | est_db | Query   |    0 | NULL                | show processlist                                                                                     |
| 248 | root | localhost:52368 | est_db | Query   | 1525 | Removing duplicates | SELECT DISTINCT s0_.id AS id0, SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount) AS sclr1, SUM(s1_.price * s1_.amount * s1 |
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The query is generated "magically" by the following method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/order/index", name="mainbundle_admin_orderentity")
 * @Template()
 */
public function orderAjaxListAction()
{
    $searchform = $this->searchForm(
        $this->createForm(new OrderEntitySearchType())
    );
    $em    = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $em->getRepository('StoreBundle:OrderEntity')->findByCriteria($searchform->getData());
    return $this->index('OrderEntity', $qb, $searchform, 't.id', 'DESC');
}
```

Nobody has changed anything in the application code or the database and it was working perfectly fine up to last friday... What could be the reason?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: As an aside, DISTINCT is redundant in this context.

Comment: what happens if you do  ```select * from ``` one of the tables?

Comment: @Strawberry yes, the DISTINCT is not necessary here but I suppose it's added automatically by the Doctrine ORM so I can't change it...

Comment: @tvgriek The `select *` works fine on all the tables of the query...

Comment: Ok in that case I would indeed use explain and gradually expand the query

Answer (score 0):

Most probably on the View side if you have tried to query the entity with the associations, lazy loading will create an additional request for each iteration, so it will be really slow if you have more data.

Comment: Hi! Yes, all the associations are lazy loaded, but the strange thing is that the application was running smoothly a couple of days ago with only a few orders less than right now. I've planned to rebuild the database using mysqldump, I'll post an update when I have the chance to do it. Thanks!